# Having troubles with Multi-Auth in Laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to implement the multiauth package here: https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth#laravel-multi-auth

for two models I have, Fan and Artist.

I installed the package per the instructions, and then I used in `auth.php`:

```
'multi' => array(
    'user' => array(
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => 'Fan'
    ),
    'artist' => array(
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'artists'
    )
),
```

I tried to emulate the example. However, when I run my original code (that was only predicated on fans, so I had the user auth associated with my Fan model)

When I get to one of my pages with one of the original `$friends = Auth::user()->friends` (for example) calls, I get the error:

```
Undefined property: Ollieread\Multiauth\AuthManager::$friends
```

When friends is clearly a column in the fans table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the authed models in the wrong way.

```
$friends = Auth::user()->friends
```

That's the old way to do it, where `user()` was the method that returned the model. Now, the first method is type of auth and I even added in a `get()` method to make it less confusing.

```
$friends = Auth::user()->get()->friends;
```

In your instance, `Auth::user()` is the `Auth` instance of the `user` entry in your config, and `Auth::artist()` is the `Auth` instance of the `artist` entry in your config.

Basically take the way that the original auth library does things, and move it all up one level.

```
Auth::user()->get()->id // Original: Auth::user()->id
Auth::user()->check() // Original: Auth::check()
```

Comment: Ok, so just add the get() field to get the entity, got it.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I added that method to prevent this confusion actually, I even wrote it in the documentation.

Comment: Just one more question.  What about Auth::login().  Is that now Auth::user()->login()?

Comment: That'd be `Auth::usertype()->login`, where usertype is the type in your config, ie, `user` or `artist`. Read the documentation for the package, it clearly states this.